# R memory management / cannot allocate vector of size n Mb

Tags: r, matrix, vector, memory-management, r-faq

I am running into issues trying to use large objects in R. For example:

```
> memory.limit(4000)
> a = matrix(NA, 1500000, 60)
> a = matrix(NA, 2500000, 60)
> a = matrix(NA, 3500000, 60)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 801.1 Mb
> a = matrix(NA, 2500000, 60)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 572.2 Mb # Can't go smaller anymore
> rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
> a = matrix(NA, 3500000, 60) # Now it works
> b = matrix(NA, 3500000, 60)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 801.1 Mb # But that is all there is room for
```

I understand that this is related to the difficulty of obtaining contiguous blocks of memory (from [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html)):

> Error messages beginning cannot
>   allocate vector of size indicate a
>   failure to obtain memory, either
>   because the size exceeded the
>   address-space limit for a process or,
>   more likely, because the system was
>   unable to provide the memory. Note
>   that on a 32-bit build there may well
>   be enough free memory available, but
>   not a large enough contiguous block of
>   address space into which to map it.

How can I get around this? My main difficulty is that I get to a certain point in my script and R can't allocate 200-300 Mb for an object... I can't really pre-allocate the block because I need the memory for other processing. This happens even when I dilligently remove unneeded objects.

EDIT: Yes, sorry: Windows XP SP3, 4Gb RAM, R 2.12.0:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.12.0 (2010-10-15)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Caribbean.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Caribbean.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Caribbean.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Caribbean.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: Try to use 'free' to desallocate memory of other process not used.

Comment: @ Manoel Galdino: What is 'free'? An R function?

Comment: @Manoel: In R, the task of freeing memory is handled by the garbage collector, not the user. If working at the C level, one can manually `Calloc` and `Free` memory, but I suspect this is not what Benjamin is doing.

Comment: In the library XML you can use free. From the documentation: "This generic function is available for explicitly releasing the memory associated with the given object. It is intended for use on external pointer objects which do not have an automatic finalizer function/routine that cleans up the memory that is used by the native object."

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Consider whether you really need all this data explicitly, or can the matrix be sparse? There is good support in R (see `Matrix` package for e.g.) for sparse matrices.

Keep all other processes and objects in R to a minimum when you need to make objects of this size. Use `gc()` to clear now unused memory, or, better *only create the object you need in one session*.

If the above cannot help, get a 64-bit machine with as much RAM as you can afford, and install 64-bit R.

If you cannot do that there are many online services for remote computing.

If you cannot do that the memory-mapping tools like package `ff` (or `bigmemory` as Sascha mentions) will help you build a new solution. In my limited experience `ff` is the more advanced package, but you should read the `High Performance Computing` topic on CRAN Task Views.

Comment: the task is image classification, with randomForest. I need to have a matrix of the training data (up to 60 bands) and anywhere from 20,000 to 6,000,000 rows to feed to randomForest. Currently, I max out at about 150,000 rows because I need a contiguous block to hold the resulting randomForest object... Which is also why bigmemory does not help, as randomForest requires a matrix object.

Comment: What do you mean by "only create the object you need in one session"?

Comment: only create 'a' once, if you get it wrong the first time start a new session

Comment: I would add that for programs that contain large loops where a lot of computation is done but the output is relatively small, it can be a more memory-efficient to call the inner portion of the loop via Rscript (from a BASH or Python Script), and collate/aggregate the results afterwards in a different script. That way, the memory is completely freed after each iteration. There is a bit of wasted computation from re-loading/re-computing the variables passed to the loop, but at least you can get around the memory issue.

Answer (score 69):

For Windows users, the following helped me a lot to understand some memory limitations:

- before opening R, open the Windows Resource Monitor (Ctrl-Alt-Delete / Start Task Manager / Performance tab / click on bottom button 'Resource Monitor' / Memory tab)
- you will see how much RAM memory us *already* used before you open R, and by which applications. In my case, 1.6 GB of the total 4GB are used. So I will only be able to get 2.4 GB for R, but now comes the worse...
- open R and create a data set of 1.5 GB, then reduce its size to 0.5 GB, the Resource Monitor shows my RAM is used at nearly 95%.
- **use `gc()` to do garbage collection** => it works, I can see the memory use go down to 2 GB

[image]

Additional advice that works on my machine:

- prepare the features, save as an RData file, close R, re-open R, and load the train features. The Resource Manager typically shows a lower Memory usage, which means that **even gc() does not recover all possible memory and closing/re-opening R works the best to start with maximum memory available**.
- the other trick is to only load train set for training (do not load the test set, which can typically be half the size of train set). The training phase can use memory to the maximum (100%), so anything available is useful. All this is to take with a grain of salt as I am experimenting with R memory limits.

Comment: R does garbage collection on its own, `gc()` is just an illusion. Checking Task manager is just very basic windows operation. The only advice I can agree with is saving in .RData format

Comment: @DavidArenburg gc() is an illusion? That would mean the picture I have above showing the drop of memory usage is an illusion. I think you are wrong, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: I didn't mean that `gc()` doesn't work. I just mean that R does it automatically, so you don't need to do it manually. See [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html)

Comment: @DavidArenburg I can tell you for a fact that the drop of memory usage in the picture above is due to the gc() command. I don't believe the doc you point to is correct, at least not for my setup (Windows, R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit) ).

Comment: Ok, for the last time. `gc()` **DOES** work. You just don't need to use it because R does it internaly

Comment: There's only one case where `gc()`may be used: free memory for another process than R. Releasing the RAM to request it just after is just wasting time with `free` and `malloc` calls undeR the hood.

Comment: I would like to add that gc() only worked after i used rm().

I had a list of vectors i removed via rm(list=ls(pattern="whatever")).  My ram still showed no difference after this call.  I then typed gc(), and my ram cleared up 4gb.  Is there a reason for this?  I have found that R does not do this automatically as @DavidArenburg suggests (at least not for the timing of my impatience).  I have started adding gc() to the end of my scripts when i am dealing with very large data frames.

Comment: @MadmanLee of course it does not, why would it ask the processor to free up ram if noone ask ?it will free it up if it needs it (on next write if needed). It's like you were emptying and closing drawers on a shelf periodically, next time you need to store something you have to reopen the drawer and put it in. That's more operation than needed. gc() fires up when you need to write something not fitting in actual free memory, it scan the drawers to empty those not needed anymore to store what it needs to write. You're messing up what R has asked the OS and what space is free in R allocated ram.

Comment: @MadmanLee just rm objects you don't need anymore and let R handle the rest on its own, it will be more efficient.

Comment: @tensibai.  I've had problems with this before.  R will not dump the memory before loading another large object.  My computer freezes and then crashes if i do not do the above solution.

Answer (score 45):

I followed to the help page of `memory.limit` and found out that on my computer R by default can use up to ~ 1.5 GB of RAM and that the user can increase this limit. Using the following code,

```
>memory.limit()
[1] 1535.875
> memory.limit(size=1800)
```

helped me to solve my problem.

Comment: Why is this being voted down? sure, its a dangerous approach, but it can often help if just a little more memory needs to be allocated to the session for it to work.

Comment: This is only a windows specific solution

Comment: lol. I needed `memory.limit(size=7000)`. I'm using windows 10 and R x64, btw.

Comment: @JeppeOlsen Why is this a dangerous approach?

Comment: @melbez 'Cause it can make your computer crash.

Comment: memory.limit() is no longer supported

Answer (score 16):

Here is a presentation on this topic that you might find interesting:

http://www.bytemining.com/2010/08/taking-r-to-the-limit-part-ii-large-datasets-in-r/

I haven't tried the discussed things myself, but the `bigmemory` package seems very useful

Comment: Works, except when a matrix class is expected (and not big.matrix)

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way to sidestep this limitation is to switch to 64 bit R.

Comment: That is not a cure in general -- I've switched, and now I have `Error: cannot allocate vector of size ... Gb` instead (but yeah, I have a lot of data).

Comment: Maybe not a cure but it helps alot.  Just load up on RAM and keep cranking up memory.limit().  Or, maybe think about partitioning/sampling your data.

Comment: If you're having trouble even in 64-bit, which is essentially unlimited, it's probably more that you're trying to allocate something really massive. Have you calculated how large the vector should be, theoretically? Otherwise, it could be that your computer needs more RAM, but there's only so much you can have.

Comment: nice to try the simple solutions like this before more head-against-wall solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Moreover, this is not exclusively a problem with Windows.  I am running on Ubuntu at present, 64-bit R, using Matrix, and having difficulty manipulating a 20048 x 96448 Matrix object.

Comment: @JanGalkowski A dense matrix? Can't you find a more efficient data structure?

Comment: @DavidHefferman, Sure I can. But the point is, this problem does not afflict Windows exclusively.  At least in Windows I can say "memory.limit(size=80000)" and, if my system supports, and if it's running R64, it'll allocate.  Yes, sure, I fixed the problem by trimming the number of columns using problem-specific means. This matrix began life as a Matrix, that is, sparse. But if I want to do something like center its entries, that advantage rapidly dissipates.

Comment: @Jan Well, who said anything about Windows? It was you that said that.

Comment: @DavidHefferman Sure. But this conversation/exchange/whatever does not occur in isolation. But, anyway, never mind.  I'll just use Windows where I need to.

Answer (score 12):

I encountered a similar problem, and I used 2 flash drives as 'ReadyBoost'. The two drives gave additional 8GB boost of memory (for cache) and it solved the problem and also increased the speed of the system as a whole.
To use Readyboost, right click on the drive, go to properties and select 'ReadyBoost' and select 'use this device' radio button and click apply or ok to configure.

Answer (score 9):

If you are running your script at linux environment you can use this command:

```
bsub -q server_name -R "rusage[mem=requested_memory]" "Rscript script_name.R"
```

and the server will allocate the requested memory for you (according to the server limits, but with good server - hugefiles can be used)

Comment: Can I use this on an Amazon EC2 instance? If so, what do I put in place of `server_name`? I am running into this `cannot allocate vector size...` with trying to do a huge Document-Term Matrix on an AMI and I can't figure out why it doesn't have enough memory, or how much more I need to rent. Thank you!

Comment: I am Ubuntu beginner and using Rstudio on it. I have 16 GB RAM. How do I apply the process you show in the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

One option is before and after running your command that causes high memory consumption to do a "garbage collection" by running the `gc()` command, this will free up memory for your analyzes, in addition to using the `memory.limit()` command.

Example:

```
gc()
memory.limit(9999999999)
fit <-lm(Y ~ X)
gc()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

Using this method I was able to calculate a distance matrix for 21k+ positions.

The size of the resulting distance matrix is 3.5GB.

Windows 10, 16GB, R 4.0.3, RStudio 1.3.1093 [should update soon]

Comment: LOL Error in memory.limit(9999999999): don't be silly!: your machine has a 4Gb address limit

Comment: R 4.3 here. `memory.limit(9999999999)
[1] Inf
Warning message:
'memory.limit()' is no longer supported`.

Answer (score 3):

The save/load method mentioned above works for me. I am not sure how/if `gc()` defrags the memory but this seems to work.

```
# defrag memory 
save.image(file="temp.RData")
rm(list=ls())
load(file="temp.RData")
```