# comparing a huge vector to a fixed number

Tags: r

I want assess how many components of  `v=rnorm(10^8)` are less than or equal to 0.5. So I wrote this

```
v=rnorm(10^8)
sum(v<=0.5)
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting this message

```
> v=rnorm(10^8)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 762.9 Mb
> sum(v<=0.5)
Error: object 'v' not found
R(3446,0xa046b540) malloc: *** mmap(size=800002048) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
R(3446,0xa046b540) malloc: *** mmap(size=800002048) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Is there any way to do this given that I can't reduce the size of vector v?
Thanks

Comment: What is our `memory.limit()`? And how many RAM do you have? Cause 1GB should be enough (`memory.limit(size=1000)`) to create vector and 1.5GB to do `sum`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you work through the random number sequence in turn, you can break the vector into chunks, eg:

```
> set.seed(1)
> rnorm(10)
 [1] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286  1.5952808  0.3295078 -0.8204684
 [7]  0.4874291  0.7383247  0.5757814 -0.3053884
> set.seed(1)
> rnorm(5)
[1] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286  1.5952808  0.3295078
> rnorm(5)
[1] -0.8204684  0.4874291  0.7383247  0.5757814 -0.3053884
```

So:

```
ans <- 0
for (i in 1:10){
    x <- rnorm(10^7)
    ans <- ans + sum(x<=0.5)
    }
```

At the end of each loop iteration the smaller `x` should be removed, so you will only need around 76 Mb of memory.

For info, I got:

```
> ans
[1] 69142375
```

which compares to:

```
> pnorm(0.5)
[1] 0.6914625
```

Answer (score 3):

See, among many others: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb), and from within R: ?Memory.

The problem is simply that the vector you want cannot be allocated (on your system), let alone calculate things from it.

Answer (score 2):

Buy more memory and use 64 bit R.

Answer (score 2):

You have not offered details regarding either your OS or your version of R or the number and tasks of other running programs. You should NOT be getting multi-line malloc error reports with instructions on where to set breakpoints with any of the current versions of R. So you may have an out-of-date version of R and should consider getting current if  that is the case. When you do not have sufficient memory you should just be getting a single line message as you did when you failed to create `v`.  There does need to be contiguous memory to hold the 10^8 elements and this would involve about 8*10^8 bytes, and with over head might be 0.9 GB.

Try restarting your OS and not loading any other programs. Start a fresh session of R without loading any saved workspace. Generally you will need at least twice the memory of your large object so I would suggest (if on Windows) trying (memory.limit(size=2000)). Then repeat your test.