# Unique combinations of all variables

Tags: r, unique, combinations

I have attempted to use the following code to come up with a table of unique combinations of a bunch of variables.

```
V1=as.vector(CRmarch30[1])
V2=as.vector(CRmarch30[2])
V3=as.vector(CRmarch30[3])
V4=as.vector(CRmarch30[4])
V5=as.vector(CRmarch30[5])
V6=as.vector(CRmarch30[6])
V7=as.vector(CRmarch30[7])
```

As you may have already guessed, CRmarch30 is a dataframe with 7 columns. I converted each column into a vector. Then, i used the following code to create all unique combination of the 7 variables:

```
combo=expand.grid(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7)
combo
```

Instead of getting the output, I get the following error message:

```
 Warning message:
In format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE) :
  corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs
```

Could someone please help me with this please?

Comment: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 512001.3 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In rep.int(rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)), orep) :
  Reached total allocation of 8089Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In rep.int(rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)), orep) :
  Reached total allocation of 8089Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In rep.int(rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)), orep) :
  Reached total allocation of 8089Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In rep.int(rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)), orep) :
  Reached total allocation of 8089Mb: see help(memory.size)

Answer (score 1):

The `as.vector` is not converting it to `vector`  For example:

```
V1=as.vector(CRmarch30[1])
V2=as.vector(CRmarch30[2])
 V3=as.vector(CRmarch30[3])

expand.grid(V1, V2, V3)
#  Var1 Var2 Var3
#1    1    5    0
#Warning message:
#In format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE) :
# corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs

 is.vector(V1)
 #[1] FALSE
 is.data.frame(CRmarch30[1])
 #[1] TRUE
```

You could have done

```
 V1 <- CRmarch30[,1]
 is.vector(V1)
 #[1] TRUE
```

But, you don't need to create `vector` objects.  This could be done by (if you need `unique` combinations)

```
 do.call(expand.grid,lapply(CRmarch30,unique))
```

Or if the columns are already `unique`

```
 do.call(expand.grid, CRmarch30)
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(CRmarch30)[,do.call(CJ, lapply(.SD, unique))]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(22)
CRmarch30 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,0:5), 10*3,
                                    replace=TRUE), ncol=3))
```

Comment: thanks alot akrun. when I attempt to use do.call(expand.grid,lappply(CRmarch30,unique)), i get an error   "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 512001.3 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In rep.int(rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)), orep) :
  Reached total allocation of 8089Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In rep.int(rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)), orep) :
  Reached total allocation of 8089Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In rep.int(rep.int(seq_len(nx), rep.int(rep.fac, nx)), orep) :
  Reached total allocation of 8089Mb: see help(memory.size)

Comment: @user3007275  Looks like you have a large dataset.  By doing `expand.grid` on such large dataset would be demanding as well.  Perhaps, you can try it on a system with better memory or use `clusters`, or databases etc.

Comment: thanks akrun. Yes, I have 1500 observations. I also have another dataset with 16000 observations and I need to come up with similar combinations for that dataset as well. is there anyway to do it in R or excel ? How would clusters give me what i need ?

Comment: @user3007275  I meant the `cluster` of systems.  If you are working/studying in Universities, they might have clusters where you can run this.

Comment: Is it possible to run this in R such that it doesn't have to display the output but rather store that output as a dataset/dataframe and that can be exported to excel ? I'm guessing this error is due to R running the code and attempting to generate the output ?

Comment: @user3007275  You may check packages like bigmemory.  I don't have much experience in it.

Comment: @user3007275  Maybe this link also helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb

Comment: I tried running the code on a server with 64GB memory and I still get an error message "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 26.9GB"

Comment: @user3007275  It means that the memory is insufficient.  As I mentioned earlier, you can check other options like clusters, database etc.  YOu may also check `expand.ffgrid` from `library(ffbase)` (though I am not very sure)