# Error: cannot allocate vector of size X Mb in R

Tags: r, memory, garbage-collection

I have question regarding memory usage in R. I am running a Rcode on our entire database in R in a for loop. However, the code stops at some point saying that it cannot allocate a vector of size 325.7 mb. When I was looking at the task manager I saw that it was using 28gb of RAM on our server.

I am familiar with the `gc()` function in R but this does not seems to work. E.g. the code stopped working on the 15th iteration, saying that it cannot allocate the vector. However, if I only run the 15th iteration (and nothing else) there is no problem at all. Moreover, for each new iteration I delete my DT which is by far the largest object in my environment.

Code sample:

```
DT <- data.table() 
items <- as.character(seq(1:10)) 
for (i in items){ 
  DT <- sample(x = 5000,replace = T) 
  write.csv(DT,paste0(i,".csv")) 
  gc() 
  rm(DT) 
}
```

I have the feeling that this `gc` function does not work properly in a for loop. Is that correct or are there any other possible issues, i.e. are there reasons why my memory is full after a few iterations?

Comment: "I am running a Rcode on our entire database in R in a for loop." Your problem is not `gc`. I'm sure garbage collection is working as intended. Your problem is your code (which you don't show). I use R quite a lot, but hardly ever need a `for` loop. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059).

Comment: I have a vector of 1,2,3,...,N and for every i, I am opening a RData file, calculate some Basel II formula's and save it again in a different folder. Hence it look something like this

for (i in 1:length(banks)) { 

load()
... do something
save()
rm(DT)
}

Comment: E.g something like this

DT <- data.table()
items <- as.character(seq(1:10))
for (i in items){ 
  DT <- sample(x = 5000,replace = T) 
  write.csv(DT,paste0(i,".csv")) 
  gc()
  rm(DT) }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R memory management / cannot allocate vector of size n Mb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb)

Answer (score 0):

View the memory limit using the command memory.limit() and then expand it using memory.limit(size=XXX)

Note this is just a temporary approach and I think that this url[R memory management / cannot allocate vector of size n Mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb) gives a much better explanation on how to tackle these.