# dplyr:::inner_join size limits

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to take two data.frames (one ~2000 rows and four columns, one ~35000 rows and four columns) and do a cross-join using dplyr.  I looked on SO and found a tip to make a dummy column on both data.frames and use dplyr:::inner_join.  I tried that but R gave an error that it couldn't allocate a vector of a large size.  (I got the same message using merge).  Is there any way to do this? a ~70M row data.frame isn't that big memory-wise.

Comment: What data types are the columns? I agree that the size shouldn't be giving you a problem.

Comment: You might find useful this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb

Comment: Mostly character, a couple numeric. I've whittled it down to the essential columns that I will need after the join.

Comment: Can you please provide the join code snippet you used, as well as the error message?

Comment: gc() did the trick... the join took no time at all after I restarted the R session and ran gc().