# How to increase memory in R

Tags: r, memory, memory-management

I am running R 64 bit on windows 7 64 bit. While running my script, I get an error message that cannot allocate a vector of size x (in my case about 200MB). My data.frame has about 200.000 rows, not more. How can it happen that there is not enough storage space to allocate another vector? 
I know that the operation itself works since the script runs through with a smaller, subsetted file.

I know too that this question has been asked before but none of the answers solved my problem. there are many different answers out-there which one is correct? Is it related to the RAM of the system or of the memory of R?

I increased the memory size manually:

```
memory.limit()
# set max memory usage is 2G
memory.size(max=10000)
```

Then r says that the memory limit is 10.000

```
memory.limit()
[1] 10000
```

but still there is the same error. it is even the same size of the vector that cannot be allocated.

I cleaned up my computer and set more space free on my drive too. but it doesn´t change anything either.

On what is the memory size dependent and how can I increase it?

Comment: Could you provide an [example that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)? It might also be a result of how you've written your code.

Comment: Related: [*Memory management / cannot allocate vector of size n Mb*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb)

Comment: One of the calculations you do needs a lot of memory. Memory demand can grow quadratic or worse with data size. Without showing your code in a reproducible example there is not much advice to give. You could profile memory demand with increasing data size and predict what you'd need for the whole dataset.

Comment: ok, thank you for this short explanation. sometimes some background info is enough. I will try to split the code and get rid of some rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

Like people have been commenting, one would need to see your actual code for more specific answers.

However, a couple of general things you could consider are:

i) using `remove()` or `rm()` functions within your script on auxiliary / intermediate objects / results

ii) read the help of the `gc()` function, which triggers the garbage collection explicitly (which should usually not be necessary but there are cases where this is justified)

Comment: Calling `gc` manually usually doesn't help and rather harms (at least performance).