# How to copy grouped rows into column by data.table in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, type-conversion

I faced memory error to copy rows into columns using `gather/unite/spread`technique in `dplyr` in `R` in another question here ([How to copy grouped rows into column by dplyr/tidyverse in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50549109/how-to-copy-grouped-rows-into-column-by-dplyr-tidyverse-in-r)).

It is the data frame that I am using as an example:
(Sorry, most of this question just replicates previous question)

```
df <- data.frame(
    hid=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
    mid=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4),
    tmid=c("010","01010","010","01020",
           "010","0120","010","010","020",
           "010","01010","010","01020"),
    thid=c("010","02020","010","02020",
           "000","0120","010","010","010",
           "010","02020","010","02020")
    )
```

My desired output is show below:

```
     hid   mid  tmid   thid  tmid_1  tmid_2  tmid_3  tmid_4  tmid_5  thid_1  thid_2  thid_3  thid_4  thid_5
 * <dbl> <dbl> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> 
 1     1     1   010    010    010  01010    010  01020      0    010  02020    010  02020      0
 2     1     2 01010  02020    010  01010    010  01020      0    010  02020    010  02020      0
 3     1     3   010    010    010  01010    010  01020      0    010  02020    010  02020      0
 4     1     4 01020  02020    010  01010    010  01020      0    010  02020    010  02020      0
 5     2     1   010    000    010  0120     010    010    020    000   0120    010    010    010
 6     2     2  0120   0120    010  0120     010    010    020    000   0120    010    010    010
 7     2     3   010    010    010  0120     010    010    020    000   0120    010    010    010
 8     2     4   010    010    010  0120     010    010    020    000   0120    010    010    010
 9     2     5   020    010    010  0120     010    010    020    000   0120    010    010    010
10     3     1   010    010    010  01010    010  01020      0    010  02020    010   02020     0
11     3     2 01010  02020    010  01010    010  01020      0    010  02020    010   02020     0
12     3     3   010    010    010  01010    010  01020      0    010  02020    010   02020     0
13     3     4 01020  02020    010  01010    010  01020      0    010  02020    010   02020     0
```

An image of this operation is shown below:
[image]

What I am trying to do in this operation are:

- Converting `thid` and `tmid` into column
- Suffix number in `thid_x` and `tmid_x` is defined by `mid`; however, maximum number of `mid` is not scalable (it spreads from 1 to 8-10 in actual large data set)
- `mid` is grouped by `hid`to define how many `mid`s are stored in each `hid`
- If value does not exist, it should be padded by `0` (i.e., some `hid` have 5 `mid`s but some have only 4, thus tmid_5 should be 0 for such `hid`)

However, when I do this operation using `gather/unite/spread` technique in the previous question, it encounters an memory error saying cannot allocate 11.4GB of memory.

Perhaps the reason of this error is that `gather` function needs to create all combinations specified in its argument before splitting them up. Actual data frame has around 80,000 records which exceeds 16GB RAM in my 64-bit version of `R`.

Do you have any suggestions to get the same outcome without making such huge intermediate records? Perhaps `data.table` may help if it does not require such intermediate operation, however I used to use `dplyr` and never used that package.
I would like to have your idea to beyond this issue and would learn new package based on the need of analyses for further steps.

Comment: Re RAM costs, seems like avoiding the operation would be the best way to go, as Moody Mudskipper suggested in an earlier comment. (The operation just duplicates your data n times into hard-to-use column names.)

Comment: Yes, this operation seems a bit quick & dirty solution. I will consider other ways for more effective ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a combination of `spread` and `left_join` to get what you need:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

a <- select(df, -thid) %>%
  spread(mid, tmid, sep="_") %>%
  rename_at(vars(matches("^mid_")), funs(paste0("t", .)))
b <- select(df, -tmid) %>%
  spread(mid, thid, sep="_") %>%
  rename_at(vars(matches("^mid_")), funs(gsub("^m", "th", .)))

left_join(df, a, by="hid") %>%
  left_join(b, by="hid")
#    hid mid  tmid  thid tmid_1 tmid_2 tmid_3 tmid_4 tmid_5 thid_1 thid_2 thid_3 thid_4 thid_5
# 1    1   1   010   010    010  01010    010  01020   <NA>    010  02020    010  02020   <NA>
# 2    1   2 01010 02020    010  01010    010  01020   <NA>    010  02020    010  02020   <NA>
# 3    1   3   010   010    010  01010    010  01020   <NA>    010  02020    010  02020   <NA>
# 4    1   4 01020 02020    010  01010    010  01020   <NA>    010  02020    010  02020   <NA>
# 5    2   1   010   000    010   0120    010    010    020    000   0120    010    010    010
# 6    2   2  0120  0120    010   0120    010    010    020    000   0120    010    010    010
# 7    2   3   010   010    010   0120    010    010    020    000   0120    010    010    010
# 8    2   4   010   010    010   0120    010    010    020    000   0120    010    010    010
# 9    2   5   020   010    010   0120    010    010    020    000   0120    010    010    010
# 10   3   1   010   010    010  01010    010  01020   <NA>    010  02020    010  02020   <NA>
# 11   3   2 01010 02020    010  01010    010  01020   <NA>    010  02020    010  02020   <NA>
# 12   3   3   010   010    010  01010    010  01020   <NA>    010  02020    010  02020   <NA>
# 13   3   4 01020 02020    010  01010    010  01020   <NA>    010  02020    010  02020   <NA>
```

Cleaning up the `NA` values should be easy enough, but may require you to re-factor them (add a level of `"0"`) or just create the frame using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It worked out. I recognized that there are lots of ways to obtain the same result.