# Older Mac vs Newer Windows - R really can't allocate enough memory?

Tags: r, windows, memory

I'm trying to run a `ziplss gam`from the `mgcv` package in `r`. The `data.frame` is `158,566 obs. of 16 variables`.

I'm using my Dell XPS 15. I only got the computer a couple weeks ago and it doesn't have a lot on it. It's a 1 TB SSD with 32 GB of RAM and the 8th gen Core i7 processor.

The model runs for 2 minutes and then says:

`Error: cannot allocate vector of size 9.1 Gb`

However, the model runs to completion (hours later) on my MacBook Pro, which has a Core i5 processor, 8 GB of RAM, and a 120 GB hard drive, not SSD.

This doesn't make sense, does it?

Do I just need to increase my memory limit on my XPS?

Here's what I have right now:

```
> memory.limit()
[1] 32505
> memory.size()
[1] 23981.48
```

If I do need to increase the memory limit: how, and what do I set it to? Especially unsure about what to set it to. I don't want to crash/harm my computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R memory management / cannot allocate vector of size n Mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb)

Comment: Yeah I read that one. I tried stuff like `gc()`, etc. That thread still doesn't tell me what I should increase the memory to. And it also doesn't help me understand why it works on my Mac and not on Apple. Those are the questions I'd like answered.

Comment: Dose your both Mac and Windows packages same architecture (x64) ?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that. Thanks. Both x64.

Comment: Is your Mac swapping?

Comment: @Roland I actually do not know what that means, so I'm not sure.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/48486