# Generating 3.000.000 strings of length 11 in R

Tags: r, memory, dummy-variable, dummy-data, random-data

Apparently if I try this:

```
# first grab the package
install.packages("stringi")
library(stringi)

# and then try to generate some serious dummy data
my_try <- as.vector(sample(1111111111:99999999999,3000000,replace=T))
```

R will say NOPE, sorry:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 736.8 Gb
```

Should I buy more RAM*?

*this is a joke, but I seriously appreciate any help!

EDIT: 
The desired output is a dataframe of 20 variables, and 3x10^6 rows. Some columns/variables should be strings, some integers. All in lengths ranging from 2 to 12.

Comment: Just wondering, why do you need `stringi`? Cause `as.vector()` and `sample()` are both base R

Comment: Also, that's an incredibly large range of numbers. Do you really need it to be that wide, especially if you're okay with sampling with replacement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R memory management / cannot allocate vector of size n Mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb)

Comment: I need a dataframe in the end of +/- 20 variables, and 3x10^6 rows. Some columns/variables should be strings, some integers. All in lengths ranging from 2 to 12.

Comment: I thought this should be super simple, but I can't figure it out apparently :)

Comment: If you narrow the range down, that will become more manageable. E.g. 
`a <- as.vector(sample(100000:999999,3000000,replace=T))
as.numeric(paste0(as.character(a), as.character(a)))` (concat the integer vectors as strings doubling the nchar, and then coerce to numeric)

Answer (score 2):

The error isn't coming from sampling 3 million values, it's from trying to create a population of about 90 billion values `1111111111:99999999999` from which to sample.  If you want to sample from that range, sample from the range 1:88888888889 and add 11111111110 using

```
sample(88888888889, 3000000,replace=TRUE) + 11111111110
```

There's no need for `as.vector` at the end, it's already a vector.

P.S.  I believe in R-devel the range 1111111111:99999999999 will be stored much more efficiently (basically just the limits), but I don't know if `sample()` will be modified to work with it that way.