# Cleaning a data.frame in a semi-reshape/semi-aggregate fashion

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

First time posting something here, forgive any missteps in my question.

In my example below I've got a data.frame where the unique identifier is the `tripID` with the name of the vessel, the species code, and a catch metric.

```
> testFrame1 <- data.frame('tripID' = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5), 
                           'name' = c('SS Anne','SS Anne', 'HMS Endurance', 'HMS Endurance','Salty Hippo', 'Seagallop', 'Borealis'), 
                           'SPP' = c(101,201,101,201,102,102,103), 
                           'kept' = c(12, 22, 14, 24, 16, 18, 10))
> testFrame1
    tripID          name SPP kept
  1      1       SS Anne 101   12
  2      1       SS Anne 201   22
  3      2 HMS Endurance 101   14
  4      2 HMS Endurance 201   24
  5      3   Salty Hippo 102   16
  6      4     Seagallop 102   18
  7      5      Borealis 103   10
```

I need a way to basically condense the data.frame so that all there is only one row per `tripID` as shown below.

```
> testFrame1
    tripID          name SPP kept SPP.1 kept.1
  1      1       SS Anne 101   12   201     22
  2      2 HMS Endurance 101   14   201     24
  3      3   Salty Hippo 102   16    NA     NA
  4      4     Seagallop 102   18    NA     NA
  5      5      Borealis 103   10    NA     NA
```

I've looked into `tidyr` and `reshape` but neither of those are can deliver quite what I'm asking for. Is there anything out there that does this quasi-reshaping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two alternatives using `base::reshape` and `data.table::dcast`:

**1) base R**

```
reshape(transform(testFrame1,
                  timevar = ave(tripID, tripID, FUN = seq_along)),
        idvar = cbind("tripID", "name"),
        timevar = "timevar",
        direction = "wide")
#  tripID          name SPP.1 kept.1 SPP.2 kept.2
#1      1       SS Anne   101     12   201     22
#3      2 HMS Endurance   101     14   201     24
#5      3   Salty Hippo   102     16    NA     NA
#6      4     Seagallop   102     18    NA     NA
#7      5      Borealis   103     10    NA     NA
```

**2) data.table**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(testFrame1)
dcast(testFrame1, tripID + name ~ rowid(tripID), value.var = c("SPP", "kept"))
#   tripID          name SPP_1 SPP_2 kept_1 kept_2
#1:      1       SS Anne   101   201     12     22
#2:      2 HMS Endurance   101   201     14     24
#3:      3   Salty Hippo   102    NA     16     NA
#4:      4     Seagallop   102    NA     18     NA
#5:      5      Borealis   103    NA     10     NA
```

Comment: So I'm using the `base::reshape` function and I'm getting an error indicating `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 54.0 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In ans * length(l) : NAs produced by integer overflow
2: In ans * length(l) + if1 : NAs produced by integer overflow`

My production data.frame that I'm using contains 388994 observations in 35 variables (36 including the `timevar`). Are there limitations to `reshape` that are going to prevent me from utilizing it for my task?

Comment: @user10598026 I don't really know. Does this post help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb If not working, then try `data.table` which is fast and memory efficient.

Comment: I decided to use the data.table function. It's much more efficient. Thanks for the help! Now I just have to figure out what to do with my terrible terrible data.

Answer (score 0):

Great reproducible post considering it's your first. Here's a way to do it with `dplyr` and `tidyr` -

```
testFrame1 %>%
  group_by(tripID, name) %>%
  summarise(
    SPP = toString(SPP),
    kept = toString(kept)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  separate("SPP", into = c("SPP", "SPP.1"), sep = ", ", extra = "drop", fill = "right") %>%
  separate("kept", into = c("kept", "kept.1"), sep = ", ", extra = "drop", fill = "right")

# A tibble: 5 x 6
  tripID name          SPP   SPP.1 kept  kept.1
   <dbl> <chr>         <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1   1.00 SS Anne       101   201   12    22    
2   2.00 HMS Endurance 101   201   14    24    
3   3.00 Salty Hippo   102   <NA>  16    <NA>  
4   4.00 Seagallop     102   <NA>  18    <NA>  
5   5.00 Borealis      103   <NA>  10    <NA>
```