# Memory allocation errors using read.csv()

Tags: r

1. First I read in the file using `read.csv()`
2. Now I want to delete that file

e.g.:

```
df1 <- read.csv("/Users/bezaa/Desktop/R/2006.csv")
df2 <- read.csv("/Users/bezaa/Desktop/R/2007.csv")
```

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 62.5 Mb

```
df3 <- read.csv("/Users/bezaa/Desktop/R/2008.csv")
```

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 62.5 Mb

```
df2 <- read.csv("/Users/bezaa/Desktop/R/2007.csv")
```

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 62.5 Mb

Comment: Perhaps try running the following before you try to read in the file: `gc()` and then `memory.limit(1000000)`

Comment: `rm(df2)` or if you want to delete everything currently in the environment use `rm(list=ls())` followed by `gc()`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb

Comment: It sounds like there is just not enough RAM on your computer to load all the files at once. How large are these files? How much RAM does your computer have?