# R: memory limit error while running R on cluster

Tags: r

I have a memory issue with R.
I'm running a big and complex analysis on R installed via anaconda in my home on a cluster from my institution. I created my environment so that I can install packages without problems. While running the following error occurs:

> ```
>    Error: cannot allocate vector of size 26.7 Gb
> ```

I checked the memory limit by typing memory.limit() but it appears to be Inf.

This is the output of my sessionInfo()

> ```
>  R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
>  Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>  Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
>
>  Matrix products: default
>  BLAS/LAPACK: /home/user/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.7.so
>
>  locale:
>  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
>  [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
>  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
>  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
>  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
>  [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
>
>  attached base packages:
>  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
>
>  loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>  [1] compiler_3.6.1 tools_3.6.1
> ```

While running the tool responsible for the problem I performed ssh to a single node with 24 cores to allow the pipeline to run.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You just don't have enough RAM. Do you even have 26 Gb RAM on your machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/5171593/680068

Comment: I already tried the suggestions as in the post but without success

Comment: @DavidArenburg okkk I'm facing the problem..I' m checking