# "Cannot allocate vector of size xxx mb" error, nothing seems to fix

Tags: r, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm running RStudio x64 on Windows 10 with 16GB of RAM. RStudio seems to be running out of memory for allocating large vectors, in this case a 265MB one. I've gone through multiple tests and checks to identify the problem:

1. Memory limit checks via `memory.limit()` and `memory.size()`. Memory limit is ~16GB and size of objects stored in environment is ~5.6GB.
2. Garbage collection via `gc()`. This removes some 100s of MBs.
3. Upped priority of rsession.exe and rstudio.exe via Task Manager to real-time.
4. Ran `chkdsk` and RAM diagnostics on system restart. Both returned no errors.

But the problem persists. It seems to me that R can access 16GB of RAM (and shows 16GB committed on Resource Monitor), but somehow is still unable to make a large vector. My main confusion is this: the problem only begins appearing if I run code on multiple datasets consecutively, without restarting RStudio in between. If I do restart RStudio, the problem doesn't show up anymore, not for a few runs.

The error should be replicable with any large R vector allocation (see e.g. the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb)). I'm guessing the fault is software, some kind of memory leak, but I'm not sure where or how, or how to automate a fix.

Any thoughts? What have I missed?

Comment: If you show the code, we can possibly help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Also see: https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf . Circle 2, "Growing Objects"

Comment: @Jason, thanks for suggestion. I was able to reproduce the error with the code in the link I mentioned. Just had to repeat the calls more as my memory limit is higher. I don't think there's something in my original code that isn't captured by that example.

Comment: What memory usage does `pryr::mem_used()` give?

Comment: @anotherfred, replicating error with the code in the link, replacing matrix row length with 7500000: `pryr`'s `mem_used()` returns 7.69GB while `utils`' `memory.size()` returns 7448MB. Rsession has a commit of ~15GB. Does this answer your question?