# Training R caret models with big datasets

Tags: r

I've been trying to train models using caret but every time I get the error
`cannot allocate vector of size 3.6 Mb`
I think this is because the dataset is too big. Does anybody know what to do in this situation?

Comment: Hi & welcome to stackoverflow. You might find some hints here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R memory management / cannot allocate vector of size n Mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb)