# Memory allocation trouble with plenty of RAM not in use

Tags: r

I'm running Windows 10 with 64GB RAM, R 4.0.2, and RStudio 1.3.1073. I am running something in the bkmr package, with only the necessary object loaded, and am getting "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 61.4 Mb". I was watching the task manager while it ran though and it crapped out when it was only using ~75% of available memory. It had gone up to 97% halfway through the hour-long run but went back down. No other programs were running.

Can it really not find 61.4MB of free space with 16GB of free RAM? Or am I misunderstanding this?

I am primarily a SAS programmer, with limited R knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: here is some [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb) that may help. perhaps you are trying to do things in r the way you would in sas which is usually not optimal. if you could pinpoint the code that is the issue and provide a reproducible example, we could be more helpful