# R Memory Problems - Session Aborting

Tags: r, memory, ram

I've recently been getting my R sessions aborted, even when running a code that I've run multiple times before. I think it could be because I'm running out of RAM memory. What are ways I could possibly solve this? I've tried removing some objects from the global environment and using the gc() function as well, but the issue persists. I'm not sure if the memory is being cleared even after using rm() and gc() as the object is still present in the global environment when I start a new session of R. It will be great if someone has some advice on this!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R memory management / cannot allocate vector of size n Mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb)

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your R session by pasting the following in your console (for RStudio), but know that it will delete everything from your global environment, including hidden files, and any plots made

```
.rs.restartR()
```