# Unable to convert a sparse matrix to a data frame

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix having more than 200k rows and 200k columns. When I use

```
as.data.frame(as.matrix(sparse_matrix)
```

I get the following error message

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1232.3 Gb
> In addition: Warning message:
> In asMethod(object) :
> sparse->dense coercion: allocating vector of size 1232.3 GiB

Comment: This may be helpful: [R memory management / cannot allocate vector of size n Mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb)

Comment: If you have 200K rows and 200K columns then you would need a data frame with 40 billion entries. Assuming each of these only requires 8 bytes to store, then you would need at least 320 Gigabytes of memory to have a data frame that large. I'm not sure why R needs even more than that here, but in any case you are asking R to create an object that is far too large for your computer to hold in memory. Why do you need a data frame that large?

Comment: Well, I want to be able to perform regression on the data. If I try performing logistic regression on a sparse matrix, I get the following error ->

Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘structure("ngCMatrix", package = "Matrix")’ to a data.frame

Comment: `glmnet` will do logistic regression on sparse data matrices IIRC, so just use that

Comment: Thank you, it worked but I also need to use neural network on that data size. What do I do?